# Installing bibexport on Mac OS X

Tags: bibtex, installing, mac

I recently installed [bibexport](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibexport/) on my mac (10.5).  This command lets you export a small document-specific .bib file using only the references that you cite in that particular document.  This is useful for sharing references with coauthors, for example.

My question is, *what is the best way to install bibexport on a mac?*

I eventually succeeded, but only after jumping through several hoops, like recompiling the "sed" command.  I would love to hear from other users how to avoid these difficulties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably did the best thing by installing GNU `sed` (I supposed it's the implementation of `sed` you chose).  GNU/Linux and Mac OS X have incompatible versions of `sed`; in the case of `bibexport` it seems to be the `-r` switch that isn't supported by Mac OS X's `sed` (inherited from BSD `sed`).

Of course, a still better way would be to convince the author of `bibexport` to make his script more portable (BSD `sed` seems to have a `-E` switch that may be more or less the same as GNU `sed`'s `-r`).

Comment: I can not see a step by step solution for the question on how to install bibexport on mac.

Answer (score 2):

bibexport is a shell script, so it requires no compilation at all.  Just place it somewhere in your PATH and make sure you set the permissions to make it an executable.  It works for me.

Comment: I think you need to copy export.bst and expkeys.bst somewhere where bibtex can find them?

Comment: He didn't write about compiling bibexport; he mentioned compiling sed.  And for good reasons; see my answers.

Comment: I take it as given that one installs the GNU textools in any *nix system!

Comment: @Jukka: indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the GUI application [TexLiveUtility](https://amaxwell.github.io/tlutility/). Within this application you can switch to the "packages" tab and then search for 'bibexport'. Right click the corresponding search result and select install. After that, you can use bibexport in the terminal.